# Chrome says CORS headers are missing even when I can see them in network logs

Tags: cors, flask-cors

I hate to be the guy to ask yet another CORS question, but I'm honestly stumped. Chrome is telling me that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing, but I can see it right there in the response headers for the OPTION request. What's weird is that on several other pages I have other CORS requests that have the exact same request method (GET), headers, and receive the same response headers that work just fine. I tried it without the query string and that failed as well. I hate CORS.

BTW, the 401 request can be ignored as it was just a token refresh. If I refresh the page I don't get the 401 but CORS still fails.

[image: Broken CORS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. There was actually a server issue in the Flask view function which was causing the response to error out and return a 500. Had to inspect docker logs to find it. There is actually no problem with the CORS setup, despite what Chrome dev tools is telling me. So if anyone comes across this in the future, just be aware that CORS may actually be fine and Chrome is just interpreting a server error as a CORS problem. I feel like this is a bug in Chrome..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to use a reverse proxy. Setup nginx/webpack to reverse proxy your server requests. You'll not run into any cors issue.

Sample reverse proxy /api/ => localhost:5000. If you use cors extention or library. It may resolve on your local machine. You'll again face the same issues when you deploy this code in production.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the plan was to serve the site as a static page on S3 so I don't think that's possible. I have control of the server so there's no reason I shouldn't be able to get CORS to work, assuming I can figure out wtf is happening here.